# How can I get WebDriver.findElements to find all matching elements?

Tags: java, selenium

I am using this command to find all the items in a list:

```
List<WebElement> layerFolders = driver.findElements(By.className("super-list-item-header"));
```

It is returning 50 elements consistently, although there are more than 100 items in the list.

The size given here is wrong too:

```
debug.print(thisClass + " collections size: " + layerFolders.size());
```

The panel goes off the page, & has to be scrolled to get to the bottom.
It currently lists items that are visible & some that are off the bottom of the page.

Comment: Did you try scrolling down and simultaneously collecting more elements and add to the `List`?

Comment: @DebanjanB. I am looking at ways of doing that.

Comment: @DebanjanB. I tried scrolling down to the last element, then re-running findElements. Returned the same 50 elements it did the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. When you scroll down through the page, this happens immediately and the execution of the next line of codes starts immediately. Since you are trying to get the all the elements with the same class name, it only gets the ones that are visible. All of the elements are not visible because after scrolling it takes time to load the content. Basically, your code runs before all the elements are visible. To be able to get all the elements, you should wait for them to be visible. You might try driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); or Thread.sleep(1000); Then try to get all the elements with the same class name.

```
//Your code should look like this
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //or Thread.sleep(1000);
List<WebElement> layerFolders = driver.findElements(By.className("super-list-item-header"));
```